# Gnome Tweak Tool is no longer allowing to move the Gnome Application Menu out of the Top Bar on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, appmenu, gnome-tweaks

Using GNOME Tweak Tool to disable the ['*Application Menu*' option in the '*Top Bar*' section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ5rh.png) (reference: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/tweal-tool-gnome-application-menu-top-bar) is no more working in Ubuntu 20.04.

How do I get the same effect now?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the application menu using the [Remove App Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3025/remove-app-menu/) extension. You will not miss any Application Menu items (e.g. "Preferences, ...): since a few versions of Gnome Shell, these moved back to where they belong: the application window itself.

Next to removing the application menu, much more about the topbar can be configured with the [Activities Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) extension, which is around for a long time and very well maintained.